# What's the difference in meaning between at and in?

Tags: meaning, differences

I would like to know what's the difference in meaning in the sentences below:

> - At no time were we friends.
> - We were friends in no time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At no time were we friends[.]

This one is pretty literal: "there was no point in time when we were friends", or "we were never friends".  The "at no time" usage is a bit more emphatic than "never".

> We were friends in no time[.]

The expression "in no time", as used here, is synonymous with "immediately" ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-no-time)).  The sentence can thus be interpreted the same as "No time passed before we were friends."  The original sentence is a little strained, but the construction is nevertheless fairly common (more so than the reworded form I just offered).  It would be equivalent, and less strained, to say "We *became* friends in no time"; that construction is also used.

Answer (score 2):

"At no time were we friends" is a simpler way of saying that at no point in time were we ever friends. Essentially: We were never friends.

"We were friends in no time" means that we became friends immediately. It might be easier to understand if it said "We became friends in no time", meaning that it took no time for us to become friends.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NDubonix, but just as a humorous aside, there's a quote by Moses Hadas that I've always held on to, and it illuminates the ambiguity of this phrase.

When someone would send Mr. Hadas a transcript of their book, he'd reply with:

> “Thank you for sending me a copy of your book. I'll waste no time reading it.” ― Moses Hadas

Now what did he mean? Did he mean he won't read your book because he doesn't want to waste his time? Or does he mean, he will begin reading it immediately?

Well, that's the rub :-) Moses was aware of the ambiguity and found enjoyment in passing this confusion on to his fans!